# Convert prefix to post

Tags: go, postfix-operator

I am trying to convert some C code into Go.

```
for i := l + 1; i < r; ++i {
    ans = max(ans, nums[l]*nums[i]*nums[r]+maxCoin(dp, l, i, nums)+maxCoin(dp, i, r, nums))
}
```

Go doesn't have prefix operator, how can I convert this loop to use postfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a postfix [increment statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements), it doesn't make any difference in this case:

```
for i := l + 1; i < r; i++ {
    ans = max(ans, nums[l]*nums[i]*nums[r]+maxCoin(dp, l, i, nums)+maxCoin(dp, i, r, nums))
}
```

The difference only matters when you're using the result of the expression formed by the increment / decrement operator, but since in Go they're not even operators but statements, it doesn't matter. For reasoning, see [FAQ: Why are ++ and -- statements and not expressions? And why postfix, not prefix?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec)

Comment: ok, I wasn't getting the result I was looking for so thought it may have had something to do with that. but good to know, thanks.